# Overflow Error, RMS value shown wrong

Tags: c

I am measuring AC Voltage and I am calculating rms value for ADC.

I have an array which is having 128 samples of my signal.
while squaring number I get an error.

```
unsigned long int calval=0;
unsigned int loop;
float adcbufval;
for(loop=0;loop<128;loop++)
{
    printf("adcval %d = %d\t ", loop, adc_temp[loop]);
    calval = (adc_temp[loop])*(adc_temp[loop]);
    printf("\t %ld \n", calval);

}
```

output:

```
adcval 1 = 168 28224
adcval 2 = 32 1024 
adcval 3 = -88 7744 
adcval 4 = -211 44521 // sqr(211) 44521 , it fine here
adcval 5 = -314 33060 // sqr(314) 98596-65536 = 33060 instead of 98596.
adcval 6 = -416 41984 
adcval 7 = -522 10340 
adcval 8 = -655 35809
adcval 9 = -773 7705 
adcval 10 = -889 3889
```

Though I defined 'calval' as unsigned long int (range 0-4,294,967,295), it get over flowed at 65536 value.
In normal C compiler its working fine.
Any suggestions?

Hardware is dsPIC30f5011 / MPLAB 8.8x

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You haven't shown it (or I've overlooked it), but if `adc_temp[]` is an array of int, then to safely square the values you must cast at least one side of the multiplication to `long` before doing so.  Otherwise the result of the multiplication will still be `int`, and it will only be converted to `unsigned long` for the assignment, after overflow has already occurred.

Like so:

```
calval = (long)(adc_temp[loop])*(adc_temp[loop]);
```

That cast may be `unsigned long` if `adc_temp[]` is also unsigned.

Comment: that is a really good point... what is the point of fixing a storage specifier for a single variable if the damage is already done, depending on how it is declared I may remove my answer.

Answer (score 0):

According to the datasheet the dsPIC30f5011 is a 16bit microcontroller, according to C99 you are correct `unsigned long` should be 2^32. However it appears that the compiler you are using treats `long` as an alias for `int` which is still compliant with C90 which simply required `sizeof(short) <= sizeof(int) <= sizeof(long)`. You might have better luck if you really need 32bit math using `unsigned long long`.

Comment: Doesn't C90 (or something pre-dating C99, at least) also have constraints for LONG_MAX and LONG_MIN which suggest that it must be at least 32 bits?

Comment: @sh1 I thought so too... [and we would both appear to be correct on that](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/589575/size-of-int-long-etc), however older implementations may not be conformant to C90... or even C89. My K&R book doesn't mention how big `unsigned long int` should be, which is why I suggested `unsigned long long` which I know should be 32bit at miniumn.